# php preg_replace using $ from the end

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to hip of from the end dot or comma and zero's using php

String is `€69,00`

Code is `return preg_replace('/[\.,]{1}0*$/', '', $_price);`

Search from right using dollar; find multipl zero's until you find the first comma or dot (from the right). Replace it with empty string.

Original request: show a formatted price that is integer, as a floor value without decimals.

String 1 in `€69,00` and out `€69`

String 2 in `€69,80` and out `€69,80`

String 3 in `€69,95` and out `€69,95`

Somehow this is not working

**question**: How can I fix the regex to make integer whole values show without the decimals when the string is already formatted (not a number)

Comment: Works for me http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6cd46e8eed78b33876e25766cc670580caeec0b7 if in doubt use `rtrim` on the strings.

Comment: jep confirmed. how strange. here it does not work. var_dump shows this `string(37) "€ 69,00"` -- the string with length 37 got me boggled ....

Comment: A couple of things to try, `trim` is one to make sure there's no hidden characters. The other is to do `strpos($string,",")` to ensure there's an ascii comma in there and not something that looks like a comma. If you're displaying this on a webpage you can do `echo htmlentities($string)` to check if there's a `<br/>` in there or something.

Comment: May be some errors elsewhere. Show us more context and how you're using it.

Comment: `string(66) "<span class="price">€ 69,00</span>"` how silly ...

Comment: I suggest using [Symphony's VarDumper component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) when debugging. It's really helpful. Also you can get what you need using `strip_tags`

Comment: Not sure but did you try `preg_replace('/[.,]0*$/u', '', $_price);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another variation would be to look *only* for `,00`:

```
(€\d+)(?:[,.]00)
```

...  and replace this with `$1`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/hIt0DZ/2/).

---

Which in `PHP` would be:

```
<?php

$string = <<<DATA
String 1 in €69,00 and out €69
String 2 in €69,80 and out €69,80
String 3 in €69,95 and out €69,95
DATA;

$regex = '~(€\d+)(?:[,.]00)~';

$string = preg_replace($regex, "$1", $string);

echo $string;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
preg_replace('/([€$])(\d+)([.,])(\d+)/', '$1$2', $_price);
```